# how to declare visual basic windows form by name

Tags: forms, variables, visual-studio-2013, declaration

I am trying to figure a way to declare windows form in visual basic (VS 2013) using name.
i.e. I have Form1 in my application. As of now, I use

```
  Private Sub BBB ()
  dim f1 as New Form1
  Call AAA (f1) 
  End Sub
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
Private Sub BBB (formname as string)
Dim f1 as New Form
f1.Name = formname
Call AAA (f1)
End Sub
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution that works. Probably not the most efficient one, but it will have do do for now

```
  Private Sub BBB (formname as string)
      For Each t As Type In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
        If UCase(t.BaseType.ToString) = "SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FORM" Then
            If t.Name.Equals(formname) Then
                Dim f As New Form
                f = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t)
            End If
        End If
    Next

 Call aaa(f)
 End Sub
```